# Trying to print data from my MYSQL database, doesn't show anything nor any errors

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying the fetch the data from my database `sunypub` from the table `journal`.

Out of many attributes, I am trying to get three atrributes which are of my use on the webpage through PHP, but it is not showing anything on the webpage.

This is the option which is directing to the page `display.php`, which will show me the attributes value of attribute `jname`, `date` and `location` from the table `journal`

```
<div align = "left">
    <form action = "display.php">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Show all the Conference List">
    </form>
</div>
```

display.php:

```
<? php

    // Create Local variable
    $taken = "false";
    $database = "sunypub";
    $password = "";
    $username = "root";



    // Connect to database
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $database) or die ("Unable to connect");
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database not found");
    echo "Database Connected";


    $query = "select * from journal "; 
    $result = mysql_query($con,$query) or die("Strange Error");
    echo "Database Connected";

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ){
        echo $row['jname'];
        echo $row['date'];
        echo $row['location']; 
        echo "Database Connected";
    }

    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php The order of the arguments does matter! (BTW: Why your code is wrong, just change to PDO or `mysqli_*`, instead of fixing your old code; + `< ? php` <- space, remove it)

Comment: Also, quit suppressing errors with `@`, you'll never know what the problems are.

Comment: `or die("Strange Error")` will never help you. at the very least you want to use `mysql_error()` -> `or die(mysql_error())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_*` is deprecated and is removed in new PHP version. So I highly recommend you to change to [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_* prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), instead of fixing your old code.

So your code could look something like this:

(Note that you have to remove the space here: `<? php`)

```
<?php

    // Create Local variable
    $taken = "false";

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "sunypub";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbuser = "root";



    try {

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM journal"; 
        foreach($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo $row['jname'];
            echo $row['date'];
            echo $row['location']; 
            echo "Database Connected";
        }

        $dbh = NULL;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Comment: @hawkeye  You're welcome. (Maybe you want to take a look into the PDO class to see how it is different from `mysql_*` and get up to date :)

Comment: I would love to have a look into it once I get my class project finishes whose deadline is approaching nearer and nearer. :P

Comment: @hawkeye Ah okay. (FYI: You can only accept 1 answer, since I see you are trying to accept both)

Comment: Haa haaa... Yeah I realised it now :P